How to change the react-bootstrap dropdown-toggle style inside <NavDropdown>?
I am using Nextjs 14+, react-bootstrap 2.10.2, bootstrap 5
The method I saw online is to go back to bootstrap.css and make changes. Isn’t there a more direct way in react-bootstrap to make changes directly in my MyNavbar.js so I don’t have to switch between different files??
For example I want to change the width of .dropdown-toggle, if I am using
<NavDropdown style={{ width: 400px }}>

In fact, what I change is the parent element of .dropdown-toggle. This is not what I want. I want to change .dropdown-toggle directly, such as width, height, ::after and so on. I understand that ::after is a bit troublesome. But is there a more direct way for me to change other properties and css? Thanks
